# Apply Q object to one object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a complicated query in a Django model and I want to do two things:

1. Get all objects that satisify the query
2. Check if one object satisfies the query

To do (1), I have a Q object encoding the query, and I just do

```
Model.objects.filter(THE_QUERY)
```

The query is something like

```
THE_QUERY = Q(field_1__isnull=False) & Q(field_2__gte=2) & Q(field3=0)
```

But I don't know how to reuse the query in `THE_QUERY` for (2). I want to have the predicate of the query in just one place and use that information to do (1) and (2), so that, if I ever have to change the query, both actions would do as expected.

Is there a way to put the query in just one place?

Answer (score 0):

`Model.objects.filter(THE_QUERY)` returns an unevaluated queryset. You can extend this with extra conditions - in this case, you can add a filter to a specific ID and then an `exists()` call.

```
Model.objects.filter(THE_QUERY).filter(pk=my_object_id).exists()
```

Comment: That would run a new query everytime you want to check if an object satisfies the query. Is there any other alternative that do not require touching the database?